# Save multiple text files to csv files

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script to format a directory full of text files and export them to CSV files. I want it to perform the search and replace on each file to format it properly, export it to a CSV with the same filename, then move to the next txt file. I have the search and replace working, but can't work out how to save each text file with its original filename. What am I doing wrong?

```
$path = "H:\My Documents\EmailSaveAs\"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.txt -recurse
echo $files
foreach($file in $files) {
    Foreach-Object {
         $_ -replace  "`r`n`t", ","  -replace  "\s`r`n", "," -replace "Bytes `r`nOut", "Bytes Out" -replace  "`t", "," -replace  "Idle-`r`ntimeout", "Idle-timeout" -replace  ",#Date", "#Date" 
        } | 
Set-Content $path $(.BaseName + ".csv")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$path = "H:\My Documents\EmailSaveAs\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -include *.txt -recurse
echo $files
foreach($file in $files) {
    $updatedContent = Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw | Foreach-Object {
         $_ -replace  "`r`n`t", "," -replace "\s`r`n", "," -replace "Bytes `r`nOut", "Bytes Out" -replace  "`t", "," -replace  "Idle-`r`ntimeout", "Idle-timeout" -replace ",#Date", "#Date" 
    } 
    $newFilename = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($file, ".csv")
    Set-Content $newFilename $updatedContent 
}
```

Your original code was accessing `$_` when it wasn't executing in a pipeline context. Note that the `-Raw` parameter on Get-Content is new in V3.

Comment: Or, instead of reading it to a variable, setting a variable for the new name, and then setting the content, you could just pipe it to out-file ala `Get-Content $file|Foreach-Object{do stuff}|Out-File ([io.path]::ChangeExtension($file, ".csv"))`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician that's the way I originally wrote it and would do it that way in practice, but I wanted to keep more of the script inside the window.  That way no scrolling would be required to see the interesting part of the solution.